# $controller is not a function in Angular/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am pulling my hair out with testing Angular. I am trying to instantiate a controller and jasmine complains that $controller is not a function. Below is my test.

```
describe "MyCtrl test", () ->
  beforeEach module('ngRoute')
  beforeEach module('myControllers')

  $controller = undefined
  $scope = undefined
  $routeParams = undefined
  mySvc = undefined

  beforeEach inject (_$controller_, $rootScope, _$routeParams_,_mySvc_) ->
    $controller = _$controller_
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    mySvc = _mySvc_

  describe "MyCtrl", () ->
    beforeEach () ->
      MyCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope:$scope,$routeParams:$routeParams,mySvc:mySvc})
    it "should be defined", () ->
      expect(MyCtrl).toBeDefined()
```

I have defined $controller at the top level scope, I have injected the controller service and assigned it to the global variable. How is it not a function?

Comment: there is a space between inject and the parenthesis, remove it, also remove the underscores from _$controller_, give it a try

Comment: The space between inject and the parenthesis was a typo. It does not fix the problem. 
If I remove the underscores from $controller, I get an error that $rootScope is not defined.

Comment: It's very odd!  Can you try adding a `dump` statement to show what `$controller` is immediately after `describe "MyCtrl"...`.  Also to check that you really are getting the \_$controller_ injected (which you should).  I'm assuming that you karma.conf.js is set up okay with angular.mocks?

Comment: Yes. I am still getting used to testing Angular (which is a minefield of gotchas), but I am fairly certain I have used this pattern before and it worked. Dumping $controller does not output anything.

Comment: I don't know what is going on, but I tried rewriting my code from scratch - exactly as before - and it worked. I must have had some weird characters in my file or gremlins or something. Very frustrating this is.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
describe "MyCtrl test", () ->
  beforeEach module('ngRoute')
  beforeEach module('myControllers')

  myController = undefined
  $scope = undefined
  $routeParams = undefined
  mySvc = undefined
  createCtrl = undefined

  beforeEach inject($controller, $rootScope, _$routeParams_,_mySvc_) ->
    myController = $controller
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    mySvc = _mySvc_
    createrCtrl = ->
      myController('MyCtrl', {$scope:$scope,$routeParams:$routeParams,mySvc:mySvc})

  it "should be defined", () ->
      createCtrl()
      expect(MyCtrl).toBeDefined()
```

Comment: That also doesn't work. For some reason, the line

    myController = $controller

generates a syntax error in WebStorm (unexpected indent). I am having this problem with certain pieces of code, it is very weird. It is obviously not an indentation error.

EDIT: I have tried it with your edit, I still get the same issue. The "syntax error" breaks Karma as well.

Comment: Try selecting the entire document and convert indentation into spaces, a common issue with coffeeScript

Comment: Thanks, that solved one problem. It made the syntax error go away. I have been using SublimeText for the last few days while they upgraded my license for WebStorm, that may have affected tabs/spaces. Still having other problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using SublimeText for the passed few days while my company acquired a license for WebStorm. Rewriting the code from scratch seems to have fixed the problem. I tried converting tabs to spaces - that solved one issue I was having, but it didn't fix the $controller error, but starting over from scratch did.